# Button Visibility only after filling all details

Tags: android, visibility, user-registration

I have created registration page, which looks like this

[image: Registration Form]

Now my requirement is, I want to make **Next** Button will be visible only if user has filled up all details in the form. How can I achieve this?

Comment: No it's not that simple, problem is much more complex than you are thinking. without any trigger it won't work, & I trying to know what that trigger should be.

Comment: This is what I was expecting, Being a new in Android I didn't knew this, Anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

you need to use `addTextChangedListener()` of `Edittext`for all fields of form you want to validate, check whether all edittext is having text or not.

Check this in all `EditText.addTextChangedListener().`
In *boolean all_data_filled_up()* method you can check all fields are filled or not(You can also add other validation in that).

```
edtMail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              //check for all edittext data
              if(all_data_filled_up())
                 enable button
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Programatically you can set the Button invisible by

```
findYiewById(R.id.next_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

alternatively in xml layout file just add

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

As already commented you should check if all EditText fields are filled out and then you can set the Button visible by

```
findViewById(R.id.next_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

To check if all EditText are filled out you can implement an onFocusChange Listener as described by RRR

Answer (score 0):

in OnCreate:

```
yourButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
yourButton.setEnabled(false);
```

make a mothodo for check if some EditText is null and check when the user put a char in some EditText  :

```
boolean VariableBoolea;
if(EditText1 == null || EditText2 == null || EditText3 == null ){// you can use a foreach too
  VariableBoolean = false; //or you can initialize it false and do anything here
}
else{
  VariableBoolean =  true;
}

if(someVariableBoolean == true){
   yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   yourButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

so when the user put a char in some EditText you call the methodo.